# Standard way to implement a Logger across classes in Java?

Tags: java, logging

I'm building a Javafx application with many classes.
I'd like to use java logging from all the classes. But all options seem to come with excessive or repetitive code. These are the ones I can think of:

1. declare Logger as a private static final field in each class i.e.

   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

This option seems kind of annoying having to do this in each class.

2. pass the Logger from the main class to each constructor

Again does not seem elegant

3. create a class just for the logger, and then call static methods on that class for each log item.
   Seems like creating an additional class just for the logger is excessive.

So how do you guys deal with this situation ? Is it just a matter of choosing the least bad option ?

Comment: I use 4. Declare base generic classes for Service, Dao, and on. I declare `protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.createLogger(this.getClass());` and then just extend from these classes, depending on the layer of the class.

Comment: So how do you include this logger in your program classes that aren't subclasses of anything?

Comment: Well, I declare a common logger with the line above, but these should be minimal classes like utilities.

Comment: If I understand correctly, like for javafx you would declare something like LoggingApplication extends Application, which would contain the logger. But how would you get this logger into all your program classes? Most of my program classes do not extend any major java class.

Comment: It's about design. I found this as a good design for my needs. If you don't then you could find another that fits better for your needs. There's no exact answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree about the "excessiveness" of the third option: the "wrapper" option is actually quite elegant because it has a dedicated class for logger ([SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) and it allows you to switch implementations ([log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), [apache-commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/), [java.util.logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) etc) "under the hood" without coupling the rest of the code to that implementation.

As Luiggi mentioned in the comments below [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) is such implementation.

Comment: SLF4J **is** this third option. SLF4J is a wrapper logger library over other log libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 coupled with option 3 (like folks mentioned using a wrapper like slf4j) which will allow switching between implementations is widely used.

```
declare Logger as a private static final field in each class i.e.

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

Declaring a logger isn't such a big deal and you should be able to define a new class template in your IDE which auto generates the logger code.